# Hibernate two sessions data unsynchronize

Tags: hibernate

I have a web application using Tomcat, hibernate and GWT framework, database is MySQL.

In database, there is a table name "menu" and three columns in that table are :

> id (INT auto increment,PK),
> name (VARCHAR(45)),
> enable (TINYINT(1)).

I define a POJO class name Menu in hibernate, like below:

```
public class Menu implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6374314909068269446L;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean enable = true;

    ***getters and setters***

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Menu other = (Menu) obj;
        if(id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

content in hibernate's Menu.hbm.xml like below:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.yabtogo.tth.server.pojo.Menu" table="menu" >
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="45" />
        </property>
        
        <property name="enable" type="boolean">
            <column name="enable" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate config file is quite concise, like below:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>   
        <property name="format_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/teatimehelper</property>
        
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123456</property>
        
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">auto</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

        <mapping resource="com/yabtogo/tth/server/pojo/SystemLog.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/yabtogo/tth/server/pojo/Menu.hbm.xml" />
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I edit table menu's data by servlet in Tomcat, roughly like this:

```
Menu menu = null;
Session session = null;
try{
   session = DBHelper.getInstance().getSession();
   Query query = session.createQuery("from Menu where name = :name");
   query.setString("name", name);
   menu = (Menu) query.uniqueResult();
   if(menu == null){
      DBHelper.closeSession(session);
      return;
   }
        
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   DBHelper.closeSession(session);
   return;        
}

*** do some other operations ***

Transaction transaction = null;
        
try{
   menu.setEnable(false);
   SystemLog log = new SystemLog(clientIP, clientHost, name); //another pojo
   transaction = session.beginTransaction();
   session.update(menu);
   session.save(log);
   transaction.commit();
   DBHelper.closeSession(session);
   return;
   
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   try{
      if(transaction != null){
         transaction.rollback();
      }
               
   }catch(Exception rollbackException){
      rollbackException.printStackTrace();
   }
   DBHelper.closeSession(session);
   return; 
}
```

DBHelper class like below:

```
public class DBHelper{
    private static DBHelper instance = null;
    public static DBHelper getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new DBHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
    private Configuration config = null;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    
    private DBHelper(){
        config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    
    public Session getSession(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        return session;
    }

    public static void closeSession(Session session){
        if(session == null){
            return;
        }
        if(!session.isOpen()){
            return;
        }
        try{
            session.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I use GWT framework and define a RPC service. In that PRC service implements class, I load Menu's data like this:

```
public class MenuServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MenuService{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -710770410849236369L;

    @Override
    public List<Menu> getMenu(){
        Session session = DBHelper.getInstance().getSession();
        List<Menu> menus = null;
        try{
            String hql = "from Menu where enable = true order by id desc";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            menus = query.list(); 
            return menus;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally{
            DBHelper.closeSession(session);
        }
    }
}
```

but after get back data by this Query, the data I edited in upper servlet still get back, which data I already change the enable column to "false", and it already change in Database, but It is still read back in MenuServiceImpl's getMenu() method, and it POJO instance's enable attribute is "true", how come? I dont know why?
Not every edited data will be read back, but this happens very often.

I use sessionFactory.openSession() to get a new Session instance, so it should not have any session's cache data, and i didn't use SessionFactory's cache not to mention that the data has been written into the database.
so why RPC service implements class MenuServiceImpl still read back the old data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Hibernate sessions's data unsynchronize, because I use Hibernate's build-in connection pooling algorithm, it's quite rudimentary, in hibernate's document, It said it's only intended to help us get started and is not intended for use in a production system.
After I change to use C3P0, everything's working fine.
I added these properties my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name = "hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name = "hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property>
<property name = "hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
<property name = "hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
```